# Understanding a Makefile with automatic dependencies: Problems with 'sed' part

Tags: regex, sed, makefile

I have followed [this tutorial](http://scottmcpeak.com/autodepend/autodepend.html). It explains the making of Makefile which take care of dependencies. I have made the following Makefile which works according to the following directory structure:

```
folder--|Makefile
    |src----|(all .c and .h files here)
    |obj----|(all objects file are made here)
    |bin----|(target is made here)
```

The Makefile is:

```
TARGET  =   exec

CC      =   gcc
CFLAGS  =   -g -I.
LINKER  =   gcc -o
LFLAGS  =   -I. -lm -lpthread

BINDIR  =   bin
OBJDIR  =   obj
SRCDIR  =   src
INTERFACE = interface
STD =   -std=c99

PROGRAMSOURCES  :=  $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c)
PROGRAMINTERFACE:=  $(wildcard $(INTERFACE)/*.h)
OBJECTS     :=  $(PROGRAMSOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)

$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET) :   $(OBJECTS)
    $(LINKER) $@ $(LFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(STD)

#pull the dependencies to the .o files
-include $(OBJECTS:.o=.d)

#the -o $@ says to put the output of the compilation in the file named on the left side of the :.
#the $< is the first item in the dependencies list. Basically the name of the .c file which is to be compiled.
$(OBJECTS)      :   $(OBJDIR)/%.o :$(SRCDIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(STD)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MM $< > $*.d
    @mv -f $*.d $*.d.tmp             #changes file name
    @sed -e 's|.*:|$*.o:|' < $*.d.tmp > $*.d    #Unable to understand
    @sed -e 's/.*://' -e 's/\\$$//' < $*.d.tmp | fmt -1 | \
     sed -e 's/^ *//' -e 's/$$/:/' >> $*.d      #Unable to understand
    @rm -f $*.d.tmp

.PHONY  :   run
run     :
    ./$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET) ${TYPE} ${INP_FILE}

print:
    @echo $(OBJECTS)
```

I have understood that it is trying to pre-process the temp file to generate auto dependency. What I am unable to understand is how it is being done. Here are the two lines I want explanation of:

```
@sed -e 's|.*:|$*.o:|' < $*.d.tmp > $*.d    #Unable to understand
@sed -e 's/.*://' -e 's/\\$$//' < $*.d.tmp | fmt -1 | \
 sed -e 's/^ *//' -e 's/$$/:/' >> $*.d      #Unable to understand
```

I have never used `sed` before so I am having problems.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you are building `obj/foo.o` from `src/foo.c`, so the file `foo.d.tmp` contains:

```
foo.o: src/foo.c src/foo.h src/bar.h
```

Now the first `sed` statement:

```
@sed -e 's|.*:|$*.o:|' < $*.d.tmp > $*.d
```

"Read `foo.d.tmp`, take everything up to a colon and change it to 'foo.o', and write the result to `foo.d`." So now `foo.d` contains:

```
foo.o: src/foo.c src/foo.h src/bar.h
```

(No change in this case.) Now the next command:

```
@sed -e 's/.*://' -e 's/\\$$//' < $*.d.tmp | fmt -1 | sed -e 's/^ *//' -e 's/$$/:/' >> $*.d
```

"Read `foo.d.tmp`, remove everything up to (and including) a colon, remove the trailing `\` if there is one. Take the result and put each word (i.e each prerequisite) on its own line. Then for each line, remove the leading spaces, put a colon at the end, and append the result to `foo.d`." So now `foo.d` contains:

```
foo.o: src/foo.c src/foo.h src/bar.h
src/foo.c:
src/foo.h:
src/bar.h:
```

The idea is to create an empty rule for each prerequisite, so that if the code has changed and a certain prerequisite is no longer needed -- and no longer present -- but it is still listed in the old `foo.d`, Make will not panic at being unable to build it.

Comment: Note that you don't need this anymore with modern versions of GCC, which provide the `-MP` flag which will do this for you (the second part, anyway... not sure what the purpose of the first part is).  Check the GCC manual to see the various types of output provided by the different `-M` flags, and choose the ones you want.  You likely won't need any sed operations at all.